# What is the local workflow for AWS SAM templates which include layers with python dependencies in a zip file

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I am having troubles locally invoking a lambda when my SAM template file includes a Layer with dependencies in a local zip file. The invoke succeeds but the function raises and error which points to missing dependencies.

When reading docs about `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`, it notes that if `ContentUri` is a local zip file, I should be first running `sam package`. Which will transform the layer correctly. Should I be running `sam package` before `sam build`, or instead?
It seems odd since `sam package` requires an S3 bucket, and that would break a local build/invoke workflow

Here are the steps I'm running (and template files)

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Simple SAM Template 


Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10

Resources:
  SimpleLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: simple_app.simple_test
      Runtime: python3.7
      CodeUri: .
      Layers:
        - !Ref DepsLibs

  DepsLibs:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: DepsLibsPackage
      ContentUri: ./layers/deps.zip
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
```

simple_app.py (`my_service` package is zipped in `./layers/deps.zip`)

```
import json
import logging

from my_service.client.my_service_client import MyServiceClient


def simple_test(event, context):
    try:
        MyServiceClient.create_plan(request=None)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.getLogger().info('Something happened: {err}'.format(err=err))

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200 ,
        "body": json.dumps(event)
    }
    return response
```

Failing to execute my function when I run following commands:

1. `sam build --template sam_template.yaml --use-container`
2. `sam local invoke SimpleLambda --template sam_template.yaml --skip-pull-image`
   Error: `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'simple_app': No module named 'my_service'` --> dependencies aren't there

If I run `sam package --s3-bucket <my_bucket_name> --template sam_template.yaml instead (or before` sam build`,` package`succeeds and return back template yaml with layer`ContentUri: s3://<my_bucket_name>/28d65cb9855cad7b8b41de3558c17baa`

I tried replacing `ContentUri: ./layers/deps.zip` in my template with `ContentUri: s3://<my_bucket_name>/28d65cb9855cad7b8b41de3558c17baa`, but that prints a message like this: `Lambda function 'DepsLibs' has specified S3 location for CodeUri which is unsupported. Using default value of '.' instead`

What is the local workflow for template with layers like above ?